# invalid cache files in ~/.cache/fontconfig

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

I created a folder in `~/.local/share/fonts` for a font. The folder has many .ttf files. I used `fc-cache -v` and I got errors about invalid cache files in ~/.cache/fontconfig.

The font seems to have been installed but I do not know if I should do anything about the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not critical, but you can force recreation of all caches:

```bash
fc-cache --really-force
```

first deletes all caches (that the current user *can* delete) and recreates them.

```bash
fc-cache -v
```

should be clean, afterwards.